# Want to modify the view of entities in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal

I want to create a module that will find particular types of entities and add a small html code beneath when the entity gets displayed.
For example, Consider I want to display some information under Videos(entity). I want to write my own module that just adds that information under all videos. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [hook_entity_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/7).

Comment: Thanks a lot Berdir. How do I find how to edit the "entity->content" so that I can add my own fields there? I'm a little confused...

Comment: That is a so called render array: http://drupal.org/node/930760 that will be rendered with drupal_render(). You can easily add your own elements, just set #markup for basic strings and #weight to control where it shows up.